# Is any way to manage keywords in Admob for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, admob

I am using official Admob Windows Phone 7 SDK (latests 4.0.4 beta version) in my application published in marketplace. And I have extremely low click rate (below 1 click for a thousand of ad shows). So I am trying to find ways to improve this value and most logical way seems to use keywords for context-sensitive ads.

But I just can't find where to manage keywords in my app! I've checked online docs for SDK and examples and there is nothing about it. Can someone point me in right direction?